# Remove row/item from RadGridView WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik, row, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have a code similar to next to load a data from a SQL query.....

```
Dim myDataset as new dataset = myMethod(params)  'This is a methos that fills a common dataset.

With Me.myRadDataGrid
      .AutoGenerateColumns = True
      .ItemsSource = myDataset.Tables(0).Rows
End With
```

So far so good....but when I tried to remove a line the object items do not nothing; the line do not show any exception, but nothing happend...

```
Me.myRadDataGrid.Items.RemoveAt(myIndex)  'Nohitng happend
Me.myRadDataGrid.Items.Remove(Me.myRadDataGrid.SelectItem) 'Nothig happend
Me.myRadDataGrid.Items.Refresh()
Me.myRadDataGrid.Rebind()
```

At the end the dataset collection into a RadGridView has the same elements....do not remove any row.

Thanks to all....

Comment: You need to remove the item from the `ItemsSource`, not from the `Items` collection. So remove the item from `myDataset.Tables(0).Rows`, and you'll probably need to refresh the grid manually since I don't think it will automatically raise a change notification.

Comment: I copied my comment to an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the item from the `ItemsSource`, not from the `Items` collection.

So remove the item from `myDataset.Tables(0).Rows`, and you'll probably need to refresh the grid manually since I'm fairly sure a `DataTable` will not automatically raise a change notification like an `ObservableCollection` does when an item gets removed.